# Type mismatch error in Internet Explorer 9: adding a <title> to inline SVG

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg

I'm trying to add a  element inside an inline SVG dynamically using Javascript. I have a script that works in all major browsers except IE where I am getting a `Type mismatch` error. The code looks something like this:

```
var svg = new XMLHttpRequest();
svg.open("GET", "image.svg", false);
svg.send();

var svgResult = svg.responseXML;

var theSVG = svgResult.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    titleElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'title'),
    titleContent = document.createTextNode("The <title> text");

titleElement.appendChild(titleContent);
theSVG.insertBefore(titleElement, theSVG.firstChild);
```

I hope that gives some context, this snippet is part of a larger script that grabs the source of an image and spits the SVG code out on the page. As the script works fine and doesn't return any errors in any browser other than IE, I'm at a bit of a loss.

Any help is appreciated.

**Note:** I should probably add that IE is telling me the last line (`insertBefore`) is the one where the mismatch error is.

Comment: That was just my example of the kind of text that might go in there. I actually have a variable higher up in the script that grabs the images alt attribute and puts that in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your code seems to work fine in IE10+
2. The problem with IE9 (or compatibility mode maybe?) is that it parses SVG using "old" document mode when it receives it using ajax. You could try to workaround it like that. Maybe there is a better way, not sure.

```js
var svg = new XMLHttpRequest();
svg.open("GET", "image.svg", false);
svg.send();

// svgResult = svg.responseXML;  <<<< this seems to be the problem

// begin of workaround
            
var svgText = svg.responseText;
parser = new DOMParser();
var svgResult = parser.parseFromString(svgText, "text/xml");

// end of workaround

var theSVG = svgResult.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
titleElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'title'),
titleContent = document.createTextNode("The <title> text");

titleElement.appendChild(titleContent);
theSVG.insertBefore(titleElement, theSVG.firstChild);
```